# new laravel package not recognized

Tags: php, laravel, package

I was writing my first laravel package, so I could use it and understand how packages work and learn how to write packages and etc. 
But my project didn't recognize the package that I wrote. 
Here is my package Github link: https://github.com/IIIphr/Shamsi_Calendar
And this is my main project: https://github.com/IIIphr/aimeos_shamsi
I use this command to add my package to the app: `composer require iiiphr/shamsi_calendar`
And it'll be added successfully (at least I guess). Then in the temp Controller, I wrote this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use iiiphr\shamsi_calendar;

class temp extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return shamsi_calendar::get_date();
    }
}
```

And a route:
`Route::get('/date','temp@index');`
But in the `http://localhost:8000/date`, I will face this error:
[image: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded]

Before, I have tried other ways and the result was anything but success.
Another thing, I have this error in visual studio code in the temp controller:
`Undefined type 'iiiphr\shamsi_calendar'.intelephense(1009)`
I will appreciate any kind of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import the library perfectly but you don't use the Calendar Controller that the package gives you. The package haves a controller called CalendarController, you have two ways, extends from this controller or create an instance of this controller, if you extend the controller from this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use iiiphr\shamsi_calendar\CalendarController;

class temp extends CalendarController
{
    public function index(){
        return $this->get_date();
    }
}
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I will test both of them now and report back what happened :) 
Edit: This code worked, Thank you for your point. You know, I'm very noob at the laravel, Thank you anyway, I'll accept it right away!